# NSUInteger Equivalent for use in cocos2d-x project

Tags: objective-c, visual-c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Is there any macro for NSUInteger implemented in cocos2d-x for use in visual c++. I need this to port a project from obj-c to c++.

And also , I have seen these  variables written after the declaration of the variables in the header file  :

`@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint stickPosition;`
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) float degrees;`
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint velocity;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL autoCenter;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isDPad;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasDeadzone;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger numberOfDirections;`

`@property (nonatomic, assign) float joystickRadius;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) float thumbRadius;`
`@property (nonatomic, assign) float deadRadius;"`

Is there use in writing these in any way in c++ and is it possible? If so How?

Answer (score 1):

NSUInteger is just the biggest-sized unsigned integer. In C++, you can use

```
unsigned long       // when building a 64-Bit OS app
unsinged int        // when building a 32-Bit OS app (ie iOS, Android)
```

instead of it. Or, to make it convenient:

```
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
```

If you want to represent a property in C++, that doesn't really belong to this topic - it's not Cocoa-dependent but language-dependent, simply solvable by reading the topic on member variables of a C++ book. Here's how:

```
class Whatever {
   public:
   CGRect rect;
}
```

then access it like:

```
Whatever *instance = new Whatever();
CGRect r = instance->rect;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help very much . How ever I need help in writing `CGPoint stickPosition; `  `@property (nonatomic, readonly)`.`The `CCPoint stickPosition; `is equivalent in c++ but I don't know the `@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint stickPosition;`.

Comment: @srikanthchitturi you could ask that in another question and accept my answer if it helped. However, I'll answer this one as well, but please, really have a look at the SO guidelines.

Comment: Yeah your help is very appreciated. I'll post this question in another post.

Comment: unsigned long long makes this a 64-Bit type. NSUInteger is defined as long (but not: long long) only on 64-Bit Mac, but on 32-Bit iOS NSUInteger is the same as unsigned int. Post edited to reflect this.

Comment: From NSObjCRuntime.h:     #if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
    typedef long NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
    #else
    typedef int NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
    #endif